# How to Integrate Amadeus GDS into WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api, amadeus

I want to integrate with Amadeus GDS, I want visitors to be able to see live flight rates and book flights on my WordPress Travel Agency Website.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-flight-search-wordpress-plugin) (and the 2 blog articles linked in it). It explains how to implement a flight search engine in WordPress (PHP).

You can then take a look at this tutorial explaining [how to build a flight booking engine](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/tutorial-booking-engine-amadeus-flight-booking-api).